# How to format some ASP.NET MVC Json result?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, serialization, poco

i've got a really simple POCO (business) object which I'm returning to the client as some json, using ASP.NET MVC.

eg. (please ignore the lack of error checking, etc).

```
public JsonAction Index()
{
    Foo myFoo = MyService();
    return Json(myFoo);
}
```

kewl. Now, this object includes following public properties...

```
public class Foo
{
    public decimal Score { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> KeyValues { get; set; }
}
```

Now when the object is serialized into json, the decimal score has a precision of 7 (and i'm after a precision of 2) and the KeyValues might be null. If it's null, the the json looks like this...

```
"KeyValues" : null
```

I was hoping to have the KeyValues NOT be included in the json, if it's null.

Are there any tricks to helping format this json output? Or do i need to manually do this .. make my own string .. then return it as .. i donno .. a ContentAction? (eeks).

please help!

Comment: It's not worth the trouble, but I'm sure someone knows how to do it.

Comment: it is when u're locking up 300 hits a second of api calls. Yes. a second.

Comment: So you're doing it for performance reasons? Have you profiled yet?  Your bottleneck may be somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ASP.Net MVC Json() method uses the JavascriptSerializer internally to do it's encoding.  There are some options to control the serialization of your classes by creating and registering your own [JavascriptConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptconverter.aspx) objects.

Comment: gotcha. so i need to provide my own code to tell the serializer HOW my poco's need to be serialized and/or deserialized.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately.  Basically this amounts to providing custom Serialize() and Deserialize() methods that iterate over your object properties and add their values to the dictionary to be JSON'd.  You would skip the null values.  A fancy way of constructing your own strings really ;)

Comment: No chance to ask for any blog posts / examples? for shi+s and giggs?

Comment: I think the examples on the documentation page that I linked are pretty good.  Where it is creating the "text" and "value" items to put into the dictionary, you would put in "propertyname" and "propertyvalue".  If I get some time later I'll try it out myself but don't count on it ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't add a converter to the serializer that the JSONResult uses.  Therefore you'll need to create your own JavaScriptSerializer and register your converter using .RegisterConverters().  Create a ContentResult and set the Content property to your object, serialized with you serializer.  Set the ContentType to "application/json" and then return the ContentResult. :-)